# Load data infile skipping 1 row in every each rows

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I'm trying to upload my csv file using mysql's `Load Data infile` syntax, but upon uploading the data on my database it loads only half the rows and I notice its a patchy row. It's like all of even numbers only have inserted and the odd does not.

Here's my sample format of csv file:

```
storeid,txndate,productcategory1,qty,totalamt,uploaddate
"1100","19JAN2019","ADD ONS","1363","333.59","20JAN2019"
"1100","19JAN2019","KFC LP","58","1736.96","20JAN2019"
"1100","19JAN2019","KFC SP","269","1093.02","20JAN2019"
"1100","19JAN2019","LTO","26","495.39","20JAN2019"
"1100","19JAN2019","VALUE","71","534.13","20JAN2019"
"1102","19JAN2019","ADD ONS","244","32.5","20JAN2019"
"1102","19JAN2019","KFC LP","9","239.91","20JAN2019"
"1102","19JAN2019","KFC SP","70","277.63","20JAN2019"
"1102","19JAN2019","LTO","3","88.48","20JAN2019"
"1102","19JAN2019","VALUE","18","99.95","20JAN2019"
"1104","19JAN2019","ADD ONS","930","124.32","20JAN2019"
"1104","19JAN2019","KFC LP","21","680.79","20JAN2019"
"1104","19JAN2019","KFC SP","196","971.11","20JAN2019"
"1104","19JAN2019","LTO","17","338.84","20JAN2019"
```

Here's my load data infile script

```
$loadData = sprintf("
    LOAD DATA local INFILE '%s' IGNORE INTO TABLE prodmix 
    CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
    (
        @storeid,
        @txndate,
        @productcategory1,
        @qty, 
        @totalamt, 
        @uploaddate
    )
    SET
    id=null, 
    storeid=@storeid, 
    txndate=@txndate, 
    productcategory1=@productcategory1,
    qty=@qty,
    totalamt=@totalamt,
    uploaddate=@uploaddate,
    unique_row=CONCAT(@txndate,'_',@storeid,'_',
    @productcategory1,'_',@qty,'_',@totalamt,'_',@uploaddate),
    created_at=now()
    ", addslashes($absolute_path));
    if(DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($loadData)){
        //$total_success = $total_success +1;
        $response['status'] = 'success';                    
    }
```

What might be causing every other row to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your local data csv file line termination character is '\n' and not for example '\r\n' ?